# How to prevent controls from being resized along with the form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

When i try to resize the form i find that the controls being resized with it

[Question] How could i prevent the controls from being resized with the form ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controls are resized in two cases

1. When the control is docked
2. When the Anchor property contains an anchor to the left as well as to the right side or to the upper as well as to the lower border.

Release one of the Left/Right and Top/Bottom anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properties so that the controls do not resize.